# Swap rows based on string condition - R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a table df:

```
df <- read.table(text="
first_name  last_name
James   Durant
'Richard Iii'   Michael
Ben     Green
'Johnson Jr.'   Tom", header= TRUE)
```

Some of the string values in the first_name column are clearly last_names due to the Ii or the Jr. suffix.  In the cases where the first_name column contains a name with Iii or Jr., I would like to swap the string values in the two rows so that each name is in the correct column.

The final table should look like this:

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| James | Durant |
| Michael | Richard Iii |
| Ben | Green |
| Tom | Johnson Jr. |

A solution using dplyr would be best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No `dplyr` here, but for cases like this, base R just clicks:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~first_name, ~last_name,
        "James",   "Durant",
  "Richard Iii",  "Michael",
          "Ben",    "Green",
  "Johnson Jr.",      "Tom"
  )

swap_idx <- grep("(Iii|Jr\\.)$", df$first_name)
df[swap_idx, c("first_name", "last_name")] <- df[swap_idx, c("last_name", "first_name")]
df  
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   first_name last_name  
#>   <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 James      Durant     
#> 2 Michael    Richard Iii
#> 3 Ben        Green      
#> 4 Tom        Johnson Jr.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use grepl and transmute.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  first_name = c("James", "Richard Iii", "Ben", "Johnson Jr."),
  last_name = c("Durant", "Michael", "Green", "Tom")
)

# Use dplyr to swap names if condition met using grepl
df_swapped <- df %>%
  transmute(
    first_name_n = ifelse(grepl("Iii|Jr.", first_name), last_name, first_name),
    last_name_n = ifelse(grepl("Iii|Jr.", first_name), first_name, last_name)
  ) %>% 
  rename(first_name = first_name_n, last_name = last_name_n)

# Print the swapped dataframe
print(df_swapped)
```

Hope it helps.

[image: R output]

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of console output in  your answers, to present runnable code with results, there's an excellent https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ package.

Comment: 'transmute() is superseded because you can perform the same job with mutate(.keep = "none").'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways of doing it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(l = str_extract(first_name, ".*?(?:Iii|Jr\\.)") %>% {ifelse(is.na(.), last_name, .)},
         first_name = ifelse(l == first_name, last_name, l),
         last_name = l) |> 
    select(-l)

# or
tibble(last_name = str_extract(df$first_name, ".*?(?:Iii|Jr\\.)") %>% {ifelse(is.na(.), df$last_name, .)},
       first_name = ifelse(last_name == df$first_name, df$last_name, df$first_name))
```